# Is there any way to run web3 as cli?

Tags: web3js, cli

On many occasions, I'd like to quickly connect to a local or remote node via web3.js and query for things directly from the console. I imagine something like:

```
web3-cli set --host http://localhost:8545
web3-cli eth --get-accounts
```

The first command would switch over to the given host, and when you query for accounts or others things it connects to that `HttpProvider` in the backend.

Is this possible? I've seen David Knott from OmiseGo created a nice cli for [plasma-mvp](https://github.com/omisego/plasma-mvp#cli-documentation), so why not upgrade the idea to a general-purpose, handy terminal tool?

*Note: I'm already running node in the console, but it's not the same sweet level of flexibility provided by a cli.*

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are referring to the [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) Javascript library for interfacing with the Ethereum blockchain? I agree. It is great.

**so why don't upgrade the idea to a general-purpose, handy terminal tool?**

Because doing so would be reinventing the wheel. Javascript can be executed in all sorts of different environments nowadays. If you want to use it through your terminal, why not just use [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/).

web3.js is available as a package through [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3)

Start a node console, import web3.js and off you go.

Comment: Yup, web3.js. I'm already running node in the console, but it's not the same sweet level of flexibility provided by a cli.

Comment: What additional flexibility do you want? web3.js provides access to every method exposed by the JSON-RPC API. The only difference is the calling syntax..

Comment: I'm a heavy user of bash aliases, so, for instance, I use `gpom` for `git push origin master`. I know we're talking about smallish productivity increases here, but it's just what I do. Devs have many different tastes.

Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @PaulRBerg `geth` uses https://github.com/urfave/cli CLI , you can extend it and personalize it as you want. Or you can create your shortcuts in javascript and load them in a javascript file at initialization time.

Comment: Answer is incorrect. There is a CLI tool: https://github.com/gochain/web3. Please edit or remove because it's misleading and unhelpful.

Answer (score 4):

There's a web3 CLI here: https://github.com/gochain-io/web3/

Works with Ethereum, GoChain, etc.

Can examine the blockchain, build, deploy and interact with smart contracts, send tokens, etc. Some example commands:

```
web3 send --to RECIPIENT_ADDRESS AMOUNT
web3 contract build token.sol
web3 contract deploy Token.bin
web3 contract call --address 0xCONTRACT_ADDRESS --abi Hello.abi --function hello
```

See the README for more information.